# python mapreduce convert text into array

Tags: python, arrays, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a file like this:

> 0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   2,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   3,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   4,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

And I want to make the first item, the key, and the rest items its value, an array of them. My code doesn´t work:

```
mRDD = rRDD.map(lambda line: (line[0], (np.array(int(line))))).collect()
```

My desired output:

```
(3, (1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

(4, (1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

My last approach:

```
import os.path
import numpy as np
baseDir = os.path.join('data')
inputPath = os.path.join('mydata', 'matriz_reglas_test.csv')
fileName = os.path.join(baseDir, inputPath)

reglasRDD = (sc.textFile(fileName, 8)
               .cache()
            )
regRDD = reglasRDD.map(lambda line: line.split('\n'))
print regRDD.take(5)

movRDD = regRDD.map(lambda line: (line[0], (int(x) for x in line[1:] if x))).collect()
print movRDD.take(5)
```

And the error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'generator'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.generator failed
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have the solution:

```
    import os.path
    import numpy as np
    baseDir = os.path.join('data')
    inputPath = os.path.join('mydata', 'matriz_reglas_test.csv')
    fileName = os.path.join(baseDir, inputPath)    
    split_regex = r'\W+'

    def tokenize(string):
        """ An implementation of input string tokenization
        Args:
            string (str): input string
        Returns:
            list: a list of tokens
        """
        s = re.split(split_regex, string)
        return [int(word) for word in s if word]


    reglasRDD = (sc.textFile(fileName, 8)
                   .map(tokenize)
                   .cache()
                )

    movRDD = reglasRDD.map(lambda line: (line[0], (line[1:])))
    print movRDD.take(5)
```

Output:

> [(0, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), (1, [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), (2, [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), (3, [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), (4, [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `rRDD.map().collect()` part, but you can easily read in the file with `np.genfromtxt()` and use a dict comprehension for the mapping.

```
data_array = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
data_dict = {first:rest for first, *rest in data_array}
```

The `for` loop will iterate over the rows of the array (each line of the file). Unpacking is used to assign the first element to `first` and the rest of the row to `rest`. Note that this is new in Python 3! If using Python 2, you can change the dict comprehension slightly:

```
data_dict = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in data_array}
```

Comment: RDD.map().collect() part is for parallelizing with Spark. The real data file is much bigger.

Comment: I see. Care to explain why your code above doesn't work? What error do you get? Or do you just not get what you want -- if so, what do you get? This may help you get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

The (non-optimized) code below might get you on the right path:

```
with open("tmp.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        first = int(line[0])
        rest = line[1:].split(",")
        rest = tuple([int(x) for x in rest if x])
        tup = (first,(rest))
        print tup
```